# $this->$array[$key] returning nothing when there is a value in place

Tags: php, arrays, class, dynamic-data

I'm attempting to dynamically use a value in an array within an object.

In my particular case I have an array like this.

```
$this->customer = array(
     [dealerId] => 4
     [billFirstName] => Joe
     [billLastName] => Blo
     [billAddress1] => 1010s    
     [billAddress2] => 1020s
     [billCity] => Anytown
     [billState] => ST
     [billCountry] => USA
     [billPostalCode] => 11111
     [dEmail] => emailaddress
     [billPhone] => 8008008888
     [password] => password
     [distPrice] => 5
     [distCost] => 20);

$result = $this->keyCheck('dealerId', 'customer');
```

The method I'm using:

```
protected function keyCheck($key, $array, $type = false)
    {
      if(array_key_exists($key, $this->$array) && $this->$array[$key]):
        return $this->$array[$key];
      else:
        return $type;
      endif;
    }
```

The first check works (array_key_exists($key, $this->$array)). But the second check fails ($this->$array[$key]) even though there is a value held in that index of the array. I've proven that the array exists inside the keyCheck() method by using, print_r($this->$array); inside the method. And I know the value I'm looking for is available inside the method by using, print $this->$array['dealerId'];

Don't get hung up on the names, or the methodology I'm using, what I'm really interested in is finding out how to address a value held in an array that is dynamically addressed in this way.

It's probably so easy that I'll be slapping my head once it's revealed...

Comment: You had better var_dump the part inside the if statement you are suspicious about and see what you get. print_r is not to trust on null values.

Comment: how about using isset()? does it change something?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, and there are no null values in the array.  The test within the method of "print $this->$array['dealerId']" produces the value I'm looking for, but addressing the index with a variable for some reason does not work.

Comment: isset($this->$array[$key]) would not change anything because the $this->$array[$key] returns a null value for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running into the dreaded *treat string as an array* trap, i.e.:

```
$str = 'customer'; echo $str[0]; // prints c
```

The `$array[$key]` portion of `$this->$array[$key]` is  being interpreted as *show me the nth index of string $array* (if you pass `customer` it will try to access `$this->c`, which doesn't exist). Assign the array to a variable first. Here is an example:

```
class A
{
    public $customer = array('dealerId'=>4, 'billFirstName'=>'Joe');

    public function keyCheck($key, $arrayName, $type = false)
    {
        $array = $this->$arrayName;
        if(array_key_exists($key, $array) && $array[$key]) {
            return $array[$key];
        } else {
            return $type;
        }
    }
}

$a = new A();
echo $a->keyCheck('billFirstName', 'customer'); // Joe
```

Alternatively, you could use the complex syntax: `$this->{$arrayName}[$key]` as suggested in Artjom's answer.

PHP 5.4 [addresses this gotcha](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php):

> [In PHP 5.4] Non-numeric string offsets - e.g. $a['foo'] where $a is a
>   string - now return false on isset() and true on empty(), and produce
>   a E_WARNING if you try to use them.

This `E_WARNING` should help developers track down the cause much more quickly.

Comment: You're welcome. Please upvote and checkmark when you can! I'll be adding more info as well.

Comment: I'd give you an UP "Useful Answer" but I don't have enough rep for that yet. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well u have to use

```
$this->{$array}[$key];
```

Comment: Interesting error when I try that..."Catchable fatal error: Object of class Customer could not be converted to string in /home/classes/Basic.class.php on line 159"

Comment: Strange. This syntax should work as early as 5.2 (and even earlier).